# Android Kotlin: setOnClickListener with Intent under Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-intent

I'm trying to create a setOnClickListener with Intent under a Fragment but I get below error when I try to instantiate Intent object with:

```
    US.setOnClickListener {

        var intent = Intent(this, US_Fragment::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Error message:
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
(Context!, Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intent
(String!, Uri!) defined in android.content.Intent

I want my NewsFragment.kt to jump to US_Fragment.kt when android:id="@+id/US" is clicked.

Thank you very much.

NewsFragment.kt

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_news.*

class NewsFragment : Fragment() {
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }

        US.setOnClickListener {

            var intent = Intent(this, US_Fragment::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        ///val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false)
        ///view.recyclerView_news.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        ///view.recyclerView_news.adapter = MainAdapter()

        ///return view

    }


    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            NewsFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }


}
```

fragment_news.kt

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="view.NewsFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/US"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="269dp"
            android:text="North Americas"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/EMEA"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/EMEA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="269dp"
            android:text="EMEA"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/US" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ASIA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="269dp"
            android:text="ASIA"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/EMEA" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

FragmentNews.kt (Edited)

```
class NewsFragment : Fragment() {
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }

        US.setOnClickListener {

            var intent = Intent(requireContext(), US_Fragment::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_us, container, false)

    }


    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            NewsFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }


}
```

Logcat Error:

```
2020-05-19 16:53:06.264 21495-21495/? E/e.myapplicatio: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-05-19 16:53:10.706 21495-21495/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 21495
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at view.NewsFragment.onCreate(NewsFragment.kt:35)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1255)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1138)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:136)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1989)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1818)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:246)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:669)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:631)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:612)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2831)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1608)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1601)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1569)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1874)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:2059)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
US.setOnClickListener {
        var intent = Intent(applicationContext, US_Fragment::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: Ok, I no longer get error message but the program crashes.
I suspect this is because my onCreateView function does not return anything. What do I need to write to prevent it from crashing? Thank you.

Comment: This is what I wrote but crashes.

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_us, container, false)

    }

Comment: Are you sure that the Button is in the same layout as that you are displaying? The error is a nullpointer meaning the app is looking for something that isn't there. You could try and wrap it in a try-catch statement. This should prevent the app from crashing

Comment: Thank you Kaedin,
NewsFragment.kt and US_Fragment.kt are located under app->java->view
fragment_news.xml and fragment_us.xml are located under app->res->layout
Is this not appropriate?
Let me do try-catch handling as a workaround for now.
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your OnClickListener code

```
 US.setOnClickListener {
            var intent = Intent(this, US_Fragment::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

with the below code:

```
US.setOnClickListener {

    var intent = Intent(requireContext(), US_Fragment::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: Ok, I no longer get error message but the program crashes.
I suspect this is because my onCreateView function does not return anything. What do I need to write to prevent it from crashing? Thank you.

Comment: This is what I wrote but crashes.

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_us, container, false)

    }

Comment: Could you please share the exact code and the error log from Logcat?

Comment: Hi Ravi, edited this post to update my edited FragmentNews.kt and Logcat error message. Thank you very much.